# Xamarin forms iOS live device testing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to test a simple xamarin forms sqlite app using Xamarin Live player on iOS device.

I am stuck on this error:

> object of type Ninteroret.InterpretedObject' doesn't match target type 'System.IDisposable'(TargetException)

I've tried it in different Xamarin forms but did not find a solution. Did anybody come across this issue and knows how to resolve it?

Comment: Just some thoughts: Where does the exception occur? The stack trace would be really helpful. And if it's user code and not auto-generated code, the code from which the exception is thrown would be good, too.

Comment: This error occur on iOS device (actual device). trying to build and run TodoPCL app on Xamarin Live device. This is freely available source code on xamarin examples. Hope this gives some clue

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the LivePlayer has limited support for reflection (currently affects some popular NuGets, like SQLite and Json.NET). Other NuGets may still be supported.

To be fair, it has a [LOT of limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android)

After i lost a ton of time trying to work with LivePlayer and/or XamlPreviewer i found LiveXaml (a paid product) and never looked back...